# Flask Upload CSV file and Insert rows into MySQL Database

Tags: python, mysql, csv, flask

I was trying to upload csv file data into mysql database. I have some error in parsecsv. Please help. I'm a complete beginner. I will really appreciate your help.

I was trying to use the code from this website
link: https://medevel.com/flask-tutorial-upload-csv-file-and-insert-rows-into-the-database/

I don't know if I have done everything as said in this website. I have no clue.

**Main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import os
from os.path import join, dirname, realpath

import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)

# enable debugging mode
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

# Upload folder
UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/files'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] =  UPLOAD_FOLDER


# Database
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="project"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

# View All Database
for x in mycursor:
  print(x)

# Root URL
@app.route('/')
def index():
     # Set The upload HTML templates '\templates\index.html'
    return render_template('index.html')


# Get the uploaded files
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def uploadFiles():
      # get the uploaded file
      uploaded_file = request.files['file']
      if uploaded_file.filename != '':
           file_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], uploaded_file.filename)
          # set the file path
           uploaded_file.save(file_path)
           parseCSV(file_path)
          # save the file
      return redirect(url_for('index'))

def parseCSV(filePath):
      # CVS Column Names
      col_names = ['name','date']
      # Use Pandas to parse the CSV file
      csvData = pd.read_csv(filePath,names=col_names, header=None)
      # Loop through the Rows
      for i,row in csvData.iterrows():
             sql = "INSERT INTO attendance (name,date) VALUES (%s, %s)"
             value = (row['name'],row['date'])
             mycursor.execute(sql, value, if_exists='append')
             mydb.commit()
             print(i,row['name'],row['date'])

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
     app.run(port = 5000)
```

**HTML CODE(index.html)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FLASK CSV File Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Upload your CSV file</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p><input type="file" name="file"></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

[picture of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhUo3.png)

[picture of file directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFQUz.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGuDF.png)

Answer (score 0):

remove the if_exists='append' from the mycursor.execute.
so it will just look like   mycursor.execute(sql, value)
if you get another error I will let you know what is the problem.